# jQuery Validate plugin, wrong validation on button click with custom method

Tags: jquery, methods, click, jquery-validate

I use the jQuery Validation plugin.

Validation happens on button click in my case (although 'onkeyup', 'onfocusout' methods are turned on). I added a custom method/rule for input.

***Problem is:***

*When I click button validation happens only with select, not with input. New rule is ignored  in this case. But when I type a text in input the rule is working.*
How to fix the problem?

```
$(function() {
    // Added new method/rule
    $.validator.addMethod(
        "testm",
        function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9]+$/.test( value );
        },
        "Use a valid username."
    );

    $("#ftest").validate({
        ignore: ".ignore, :hidden",
        focusInvalid: true,
        rules: {
            i1:"required",
            i2: {
                testm: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            i1: "error1",

        }
    });

    // I need to check whether form is valid when I click the button
    $("#btest").click(function() {
        //alert('asd');
        var valid = $("#ftest").valid();
        if(valid)
        {
            alert('good');
        }
        else {
            alert('bad');
        }
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qwJcf/

Comment: **NOTE:**  You should remove the line `focusInvalid: true,` entirely.  This is already the default state of this option.  As sometimes mentioned in the documentation, setting certain options to their default can break the plugin.  If declared, this option should be only set to `false`.  The option should not be declared at all if you want it `true`.

Comment: **Another NOTE:**  You do not need the `$("#btest").click()` handler function at all.  This is merely duplicating the default behavior of the plugin.  Just make sure your button is a `type="submit"` and the rest is automatic!  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/qwJcf/3/ ~  You do not even need the `submitHandler` or `invalidHandler` callback functions; I only added those to demonstrate your alerts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make the empty input fail the validation, you need to remove this line from the testm validation method:

`this.optional(element) ||`

http://jsfiddle.net/qwJcf/1/

Comment: My inattentiveness, my mistake. Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.